# How to Access newly added view from linearlayout manager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I am making a chat application .
I have a Layout manager which extends LinearLayoutManager and i want to compute the height of the view added to the adapter so that when i call smoothScrollToPosition() then i could change the scroll speed.

For more height i will make MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH to a smaller value and for less height i will make it large.

But i am not able to calculate the height of the newly added view.

```
public class SmoothLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private ChatAdapter mChatAdapter;
private Context mContext;
private final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 250f;
public SmoothLinearLayoutManager(Context context,ChatAdapter adapter) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mChatAdapter = adapter;
}

public SmoothLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    mContext = context;
}

public SmoothLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(final RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

    Log.d("Scroll",mChatAdapter.getChildHeight()+"");

    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {
        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return SmoothLinearLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(position);
        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            return (MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH)/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }
    };
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose of accessing newly added view is to make constant smoothscroll speed, this library may be useful for you.
https://github.com/nshmura/SnappySmoothScroller

like this:

```
layoutManager = new SnappyLinearLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setSnapDuration(500);
layoutManager.setSeekDuration(1000);
```

Comment: This will have constant speed for all, the newly added view is not visible initially because it is in the bottom and I have to scroll to that position, now since it's is not visible,it is not in the onBindView , so my question was whether we can measure the height of the newly added view which is not visible ?

Comment: The height of newly added view is determined in View#onMeasure method.
View#onMeasure method is called after RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindView method call.
So I think there is no way to measure the height of view before RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindView method call.